Looking for piece name/number, it looks like a wedge with 4 studs
I am looking for the name of a piece. I haven't seen this piece before, but it's a perfect match for micro scale NEMO museum in Amsterdam. It looks like a wedge, but I can't find it with the search term 'wedge'. I think its size is 2x6, maybe 2x5. Looks like a piece from a vehicle/spaceship.
I found this piece on https://ideas.lego.com/activities/df8a6c3f-5c76-436a-a278-e01a5cbdc178/response/38f567a3-c43c-40b0-9255-9a89f6bf63e9.
Anyone familiar with this particular piece? The colour is from a render, so not necessarily an existing colour for this piece.
Many thanks!
I have added 2 pictures of it:



Have you tried taking a pic (of just the piece you are looking for to make it easier to narrow down) and searching google image search?  That has helped me find part numbers before.

Hi Brad, the second picture shows the piece I'm looking for, Google or brickognize could not find it I'm afraid. Its a render, so I don't have a physical example unfortunately

I believe this is an assembly of (at least) three parts:


11477 Slope brick curved 2x1
29120 Slope brick curved 2x1 with left cutout
41770 Wing 2x4 left

I also think that the three indentations of the wing are visible (albeit barely) in the original image under the 4x4 tile.

Good call, you might be right

All three are available in sand green as well, great! Many thanks mate
